# How to add line-breaks to a textarea with text over more lines

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am using a textarea width about 300px with, 2 rows and a maxlength.

If the text is two rows long I do not receive any line breaks (`<br/>` or \n ) in the $_POST var.

PHP var_dump output of the textarea $_POST:

```
string(35) "test test test test test test test "
```

HTML:

```
<textarea name="text-1" id="text-1" rows="2" maxlength="35">Click here to enter text</textarea>
```

CSS:

```
#text-1, #text-2 {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 228px;
    height: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: center;
    resize: none;
    font: bold 21px 'Impact', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow:  2px  2px 2px black,
                  2px -2px 2px black,
                 -2px  2px 2px black,
                 -2px -2px 2px black;
}
```

I want to achieve this output depending on where the natural breakpoint into the second row is:

```
string(35) "test test test test test\n test test "
```

Any ideas if thats possible?

Comment: if it is on 2 rows, it is likely there isn't a newline in there. the newline will only show if there is an explicit newline added by pressing enter. Typically what you see as newline is just a wordwrap which wouldn't send a newline character because there isn't one. If using a fixed width font (aka monospace font) you can estimate the number of characters for the width and add your own newline. Other than that, you would be guessing as to the width of the text and just insert after X characters.

Comment: Ok... But i need one. Any suggestions to achieve this somehow?

Comment: You could insert a newline after X characters, but you would just be guessing as to the width of the text unless you had a fixed width font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the attribue `wrap="hard"` and it will send a newline wherever it wraps:

```
<textarea wrap="hard" name="text-1" id="text-1" rows="2" maxlength="35">Click here to enter text</textarea>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Edit:

> the cols attribute must be specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate it if you use [the wordwrap function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

```
$out = wordwrap($string, 70);
```

or, if you need HTML breaks

```
$out = wordwrap($string, 70, "<br />\n");
```

PS Make sure you're sanitizing the input before hand so you're not vulnerable to XSS and other attacks.